# Removing duplicates in Laravel relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with a situation where people and employers are related through licenses. So my models look something like this:

```
class Employer extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function people()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class, 'licenses');
    }
    // &c
}

class Person extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function employer()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Employer::class, 'licenses');
    }
    // &c
}
```

However, person-employer pairs can have multiple licenses. So the aforementioned relationship returns duplicate Person entities, namely one Person entity for every License entity associated with the employer.

How do I fix this issue so that these relationships only return unique entities?

Comment: did you try `groupBy` with relation?

Comment: How do you save the relationships, as the standard way of saving them would not allow duplicates.

Comment: Can you show the query you are performing? I think that's the most important part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try laravel `$collection->unique('licence_number')`
so whatever eloquent returns you in collection just use unique with attribute
on the basis of you want to make the result unique like
licence_number is in the collection

`[ { licence_number:1, name:'test' }, { licence_number:2, name:'jhon' } ]`